# URLError: urlopen error timed out

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2

Whenever i try to make a HTTP request to some url through my django application which is running on top of apache mod_python (Machine: Ubuntu 10.04 server edition, 64-bits), it gives a timeout error.

The strange thing is that it works fine on Ubuntu 10.04 server edition, 32-bits.
I feel there could be some proxy connection issue. But i am not sure how to resolve it, if that is the case.

What could be the issue? Can anyone please throw some light on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run simple network analysis first, 
tracert
ping 
wireshark (for network analysis)

Check your firewall and proxy settings on the server and make sure the correct ports, routes and permissions are fine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this how to do that?

Comment: Get on your command line and then run, ping <target>, tracert <target>. Then download wireshark http://www.wireshark.org/ and run a it while connecting (make sure other traffic is kept down)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Try it in the python shell first. Just take whatever you're trying to do with urlopen and do it in the python shell. You need to simplify your test.

Step 2:

If it still doesn't work maybe it's network... trying pinging the domain.

```
# ping domain.com
```

Could be a DNS issue, try looking the domain up:

```
# nslookup domain.com
or
# dig domain.com
```

If this works try pinging the IP directly.

```
# ping 000.000.000.000
```

Without more details this is all I know to try.